# How do you disable the background view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to make my background view disable on button click event or any other event like as UIAlertView view comes which makes background view Non Active.
How to do that? please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```